# Flutter: Making a background for an icon

Tags: flutter, user-interface, frontend, alignment

There are a few questions like this, but none seem to work for my use case. I am implementing a widget in the following way, where size is a passed in double:

```
Container(
          margin: margin,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.verified,
            color: ExtraColors.highlightColor,
            size: size,
          )),
```

Which is looking like:
[image]

Any idea what I can do to fit the white behind the icon? Padding does not seem to affect it, and shifting the sizes seems to throw the whole thing out of whack.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide sample data on snippet, and try removing `margin: margin,`(also think this isnt the issue)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to make your circle transparent. So, just use this:

```
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
      )
```

or this,

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.transparent,
      )
```